# How to copy the editable select(dropdown) plugin value to a textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using editable select plugin jquery it is running well with this code with database source link

```
     <script>
      $(function () {
      $('#myddl').editableSelect();
                 });
      </script>
```

but i want to copy the selected value text to a text box ,have a code but that not working  which is here

```
   <script>
      $('#onselect').editableSelect({
       onSelect: function (element) {
    $('#afterSelect').html($(this).val());
                      }
        });
   </script>
```

I will be very grateful if someone helps me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select) plugin, the instructions on that page shows that in order to handle the select event you use the following format...

```
$('#onselect').editableSelect().on('select.editable-select', function (e) {
  $('#afterSelect').html($(this).val());
});
```

(On a side note, I really hope that isn't how you format your code... I'd reject that immediately on a review.)

Comment: Thanks Sir for the answer , i have tried many versions of this code nothing is working..actually the plugin is a searchable dropdown which on typing changes into text box like search, i want to get the selected value of dropdown list to be copied in the another text box..

Comment: Sorry, but without confirmation of exactly which plugin you're using, I cannot help you... I simply put `editableSelect` into Google and that was the most obvious plugin I could find

Comment: i m using this plugin https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select, but it is not leting me copy the selected item of dropdown list to the text box..thnks for reply

Comment: That's **exactly** the plugin I've referenced, so I have no idea why it's not working for you